# Serve apache error logs for debugging

Tags: django, apache, git, deployment, logging

I've setup a server to automatically deploy the trunk of our repository whenever it changes to a live apache-hosted wsgi subdomain. This works great *except* when there is a server error, because the team can't debug it because apache slaps a generic 500 error page up.

To debug, it is necessary to ssh in to the server and tail the /var/log/apache2/error file, which is quite a barrier for a developer who just wants to fix a typo.

**How can I publish (with access restricted by IP or .htaccess) the log files so that the team can easily check what they have broken in apache?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django error reporting feature. Have a look at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'd forgotten about that, that's much more satisfactory!